# Pythonic, custom warnings

Tags: python, python-3.x, warnings

**Basic question:** What's the most Pythonic/logical way to make my own, custom warning classes? What are the correct warning and exception classes that I should be subclassing?

**Motivation**: The requirements for the library I'm writing specify that if a `MyContainer` object `c` contains an item `x` and the caller of the library tries to place a "duplicate" of `x` -- call it `y` -- into `c`, a warning is issued to the caller and the return value of `c.my_transformation_method(x, y)` is placed into `c` to replace `x`. In other words, `MyContainer`s will replace elements with their duplicates, but must warn the user when doing so.

Based on my reading, the most flexible way to warn the caller of a library about a nonfatal action is with the [warnings standard module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/warnings.html). It allows the caller to handle the warning as it sees fit, doing anything from ignoring warnings to treating them as errors. (Note that I'm using Python 3, but I don't think that's essential to the question here.)

**Example:** What I've done is defined the following warning subclass:

```python
class DuplicateItemWarning(UserWarning, ValueError):
    pass
```

Then the `add()` method of `MyContainer` calls `warnings.warn('detected duplicate', DuplicateItemWarning)` when it detects an attempt to insert a duplicate item.

**Specific questions:**

1. Should I be subclassing `UserWarning` as above, or just sublcassing `Warning`?
2. It seems semantically sensible to subclass `ValueError` (which, in the above example, merely inserts `ValueError` in the MRO between `Warning` and `Exception`) in case a caller wants to treat warnings as errors. Is there a drawback to this I'm not seeing?
3. I could find no previous questions on StackOverflow about customizing warning classes. Is this because Python programmers don't even like using the `warnings` module?

Comment: IMO, the most pythonic approach is to just use the built in warnings and exceptions, providing your own message. What is the case for subclassing?

Comment: @Wilduck I may need to create other kinds of warnings for this library, but also I like the semantics of having a warning that is also a `ValueError`. In any case, what's the correct built-in warning to use for this situation? `Warning`? `UserWarning`?

Comment: I think it's certainly not `Warning`. It's the base class of all warnings. See http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/warnings.html#warning-categories for a full list, it depends on what your warning should mean

Comment: I would say `RuntimeWarning`. This is what numpy uses for divide by zero warnings: `np.array([1,2,3]) / np.array([1,0,1])` gives a `RuntimeWarning`. If a major package like numpy doesn't need to subclass warnings, I would argue that you'd need a pretty good case for why your application would need to.

Comment: Thanks, @Wilduck. I'm still interested in anyone's direct answer to the question, but this will give me something to think about.

Comment: @jadkik94: That makes sense. @Wilduck thinks I should use `RuntimeWarning` without subclassing like `numpy` does. Let's say I still want to subclass -- what's the semantic difference between subclassing `UserWarning` and `RuntimeWarning`?

Comment: A warning is not an error, so mixing an error/exception class and a warning class sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @ThiefMaster It is (or _can_ be) an error. "Warning -- this is the base class of all warning category classes and it itself a subclass of Exception". See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0230/.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After reading the [PEP 230](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0230/) about the warning framework and the warnings docs, I think I have the answer to your questions:

1. `UserWarning` and all others are warning categories, they don't seem to have another role than just classification. This way you could filter them out in your production environment for example. So, basically, you could subclass from `Warning` if the warning does not fall in any other category. If **in the context**, `UserWarning` or `RuntimeWarning` seem enough, just use them.
2. `Warning`s are already `Exception`s. So, technically, to "catch" them as errors, you just need to change the filter, no need to subclass from any `XXXError`. Now, again it's all about making sense. If the warnings are about the values passed, you could subclass from `ValueError`, especially if there would be many different custom warnings, you would expect the caller to "catch" all warnings regarding values all at once.

   ```python
   try:
        # do something
   except MyCustomWarningOne:
       # do something else
   except MyCustomWarningTwo:
       # do something else also
   except ValueError: # or RuntimeWarning if you subclass from it
       # catch some other warning (both of these subclass from ValueError for example)
   ```
3. The `warnings` module is Guido van Rossum's idea. (See PEP 230). If that ain't Pythonic enough ... :D

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, my subclassing approach is good as long as that makes my warnings make the most intuitive sense for users. Avoiding subclassing, _i.e._, using `RuntimeWarning` directly (`UserWarning` seems like a cop-out now since its name is so non-specific) is good when my library doesn't have many different warnings to give. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I think it makes sense to do this, but I can't guarantee this is the way you should go about it. See other opinions too :)

Comment: Using `Warning` as the base class and the mentioned *filtering* means that you can easily catch+report+ignore all warnings in the `except Warning as warn:` clause -- including those that you did not invented.